# error: incompatible type object cannot be converted to (java class)

Tags: java, android

I have java class adapter and this is error (Groceries b : getData()), because object cannot be converted to Groceries.java, if i change to (Object b : getData()) i can't call a method b.getProduct().getSn() from Groceries.java

DataAdapter.java

```
public Groceries getBelBySN(String sn) {
    Groceries pp = null;
    for (Groceries b : getData()) {
        if (b.getProduct().getSn().equals(sn)) {
            pp = b;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pp;
}

public void updateTotal() {
    long jumlah = 0;
    for (Groceries b : getData()) {
        jumlah = jumlah + (b.getProduct().getHarga() * b.getQuantity());
    }
    total = jumlah;
}
```

This is Groceries.java that i call on adapter

```
public class Groceries {
protected Product product;
protected int quantity;

public Groceries(Product product, int quantity) {
    this.product = product;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
```

Comment: What does `getData()` return? Can you show us the code of `getData()`?

Comment: getData() is from List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `getData()` doesnt return a Groceries object. Could you provide the implementation for it, please. 
Every object in Java inheritates from Object.class that's why you can cast to it without any problems. The Object.class doesn't have any of your Groceries functions, that's why you get an error calling them. You should probably read a good book about OOP and OOP in Java first.

**EDIT:**

I don't know how your `getData()` function looks like, but it should be something like this to make the advanced for loop work:

```
ArrayList<Groceries> myGroceries = new ArrayList<Groceries>();

public ArrayList<Groceries> getData(){
    return myGroceries;
}
```

Then your loop should run just fine.

```
for (Groceries b : getData()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```